# Error building Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

When I build Core-NLP on my own, I get the following message:

```
incompatible types; no instance(s) of type variable(s) VALUE exist so that VALUE conforms to Map<Integer,String>
```

The offending line:

```
Map<Integer,String> roleMap = ((CoreLabel)t1.label()).get(CoreAnnotations.CoNLLSRLAnnotation.class);
```

The offending function:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public <VALUE, KEY extends Key<CoreMap, VALUE>>
    VALUE get(Class<KEY> key) {
    for (int i = size; i > 0; ) {
   if (keys[--i] == key) {
    return (VALUE)values[i];
  }
}
    return null;
}
```

I really have no clue how to fix this. I'm trying to build CoreNLP with Maven so I can use it easily in my project. Ideas?

Comment: What Java compiler are you using?

Comment: Why is the offending line not in the offending function?

Comment: @simplyianm, Maven is not a compiler.  Which `javac` are you using?

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen I had a feeling that was going to make me look stupid :) I don't know, it's the one that comes default with Netbeans. I tried doing `javac -version` in the command prompt, but nothing came up.

Comment: @simply, according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037265/what-javac-is-netbeans-using), you can check by going to Tools->Java Platforms

Comment: CoreLabel uses a Josh Bloch-style heterogeneous typed map, which stresses the implementation of generics. It is indeed likely that the answer is to upgrade the compiler.  E.g., if it is an early build of jdk1.5.

Comment: @ChristopherManning - Christopher, sorry to bug you on such an old question. I'm actually having the same exact problem, and others also seem to [have](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/java-nlp-user/2012-March/001924.html). My version of `javac` is `1.7.0_65` so I guess there must be some other problem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @ChristopherManning - I'm building the python interface to the Stanford Parser under linux ubuntu 12.04 (Jpype is installed) with the command `rake setup` in the directory `/3rdParty/stanford-parser`. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Not an aswer but just a friendly reminder to us all: RTFM. http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml > Usage notes
>
> The current version of the parser requires Java 8 (JDK1.8) or later. (You can also >download an old version of the parser, version 1.4, which runs under JDK 1.4, version 2.0 which runs under JDK 1.5, version 3.4.1 which runs under JDK 1.6, but those distributions are no longer supported.) The parser also requires a reasonable amount of memory (at least 100MB to run as a PCFG parser on sentences up to 40 words in length; typically around 500MB of memory to be able to pa

Answer (score 1):

Where are you grabbing your source from?

I had no problem building [from the master branch on their github repository](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP).  I'm using java 1.8, which is required in their maven pom.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I experienced this error when running [this](http://projects.csail.mit.edu/spatial/Stanford_Parser) python wrapper of the Stanford NLP.